# No value specified for parameter 1

Tags: java, database, hibernate, postgresql

I am using **Hiberante** to connect to **postgres** database. I am trying to insert a record into the database. I have the values for the record in a string array which I got from a csv file. This is my dao code

```
StringBuffer query=new StringBuffer("insert into t_wonlist values(");
        for(int i=0;i<67;i++){
            query.append(values[i]+",");
        }
        query.deleteCharAt(query.lastIndexOf(","));
        query.append(");");

        sessionfactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(query.toString()).executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("Query executed");
        sessionfactory.getCurrentSession().flush();
```

I am using StringBuffer, so that I can append the values into the query using a for loop.

but when I execute the query I am getting the following exception

```
 org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No value specified for parameter 1.
```

I am sure that the number of parameters is correct. Can someone help me. Thanks

Comment: Please read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection then switch to using parameterised queries ("prepared statements"). You should never need to build a simple insert query with a string builder and doing so is dangerously insecure - see http://bobby-tables.com/  . You'll need to show the *exact text* of the SQL corresponding to that error if you want any help with the code as it stands now.

Comment: One of the `values[i]`s is a question mark, isn't it?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight ... and hasn't been correctly quoted, probably.

Answer (score 4):

You're approaching this in a bizarre and backwards manner.

The immediate problem is probably failure to escape/quote a `?` in one of the input strings, so PgJDBC thinks it's a query parameter. That doesn't mean you should fix it by escaping/quoting question marks, it's a sign you're taking entirely the wrong approach.

Please read [this page on SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and [this site](http://bobby-tables.com/).

You're using the Hibernate ORM, so you'd usually be using the JPA interface or the direct Hibernate interface to create new domain objects and persisting them. The typical approach is to `new` an object, then use the `EntityManager.persist` method (if using JPA) or the `Session.save` method (if using Hibernate directly) to persist the entities.

If you want to use direct JDBC instead you should be creating a JDBC `PreparedStatement`, setting its parameters, and then applying it. See [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html). Since you're loading CSV you'd usually do this in a JDBC batch, though this doesn't actually gain you much in PostgreSQL.

Better yet, since you're importing CSV you can probably just use PostgreSQL's built-in `COPY` command via PgJDBC's [CopyManager](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/copy/CopyManager.html) to stream the changes efficiently into the target table.